# Ansible Task Installing wrong NodeJS version

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible playbook which configures a remote artifactory repo, deletes the default nodesource repo, and installs the nodejs package from artifactory, as follows:

```
- name: Ensure Node.js and npm are installed.
  yum: "name=nodejs-18.16.0-1nodesource state=present disable_excludes='all' disable_plugin='*' disablerepo='*rhui*,*rhel*'"
```

I run this ansible playbook against two fresh EC2 servers with identical AMIs. One is successful, one fails with:

```
"name": [
  "nodejs-18.16.0-1nodesource"
]

Failed to download packages: nodejs-2:18.16.0-1nodesource
```

As you can see, the nodejs version it tries to install is incorrect, I have no idea where it is getting the 2: from.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It depens of the repo you have enabled. Appear you have not enabled the repo that contain nodejs-2:18.16.0-1